# Fn Lock key blink/flash randomly on Lenovo Xiaoxin Laptop in linux

Tags: linux, laptop, keyboard, lenovo-laptop, fn-key

I am on a Lenovo Xiaoxin Pro16 2022 AMD Laptop and sometimes, the fn lock key would blink randomly, not like error codes you would encounter during boot but very fast flashes and not at "full brightness" of the LED (I presume it's my eyes smoothing similar to PWM for displays). I can activate fn lock fine and the indicator works as well shining brightly. I am running KDE Plasma on Manjaro (23.0.2 Uranos) with kernel version 6.5.3-1-MANJARO

- This problem does not occur on Windows (which I dual boots) and I believe did not occur in the past when I used linux. All other keys and indicators (caps lock, num lock, led on the power button) are working fine.
- I had swapped caps lock with esc (where the fn lock key and indicator also is at) through the settings application (I did this on windows too using PowerToys but not problems there) but I have removed that setting with the problem persisting.
- I only observed it in dark places which I also happen to be unplugged as well. I found some posts online with people having the key fail when unplugged/plugged in but I dont believe so.

I believe that the indicator is not controllable by any user applications so should be the driver/firmware messing with me, but I have no clue where to go from here. So I would like to ask suggestions where to get more information to debug the problem.

For now I am going to boot some different live usbs.